# Check if large list of words has specific length

Tags: java, arrays

I have a dictionary text file of around 60000 words. I would like to read in that text file and see if it has a certain amount of n words, provided by the user. At the recommendation of my Professor, I'm going to create a method that expands the array to compensate the different n values. I know how to do that. My question is, how do I initially read the text file and determine if each of the 60000 words has a specific n length?

I know I have to use a loop and import the file: (although I've never done throw exception)

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("2of12inf.txt"));

for(int i = 0; i < sizeWord; i++) {
}
```

But what I would normally do is use a `charAt(i)` , and check if the word has n many characters. But I can't possibly do that for 60000 words. Suggestions?

Comment: Well, there are `Scanner#hasNext` `Scanner#nextLine` and `String#length`, and you also have `while` statements.

Comment: Are you asking how to read in words from a text file, or how to determine their size?

Comment: @Scott Hunter Well, I'm not comfortable with text file, so I'd appreciate any feedback. But my major concern is how to determine the size of each 60000 words in the text file.

Comment: Open the text file, start reading it using FileStream..start a for loop, within it start a counter, check each word length, and increase the counter whenever the word length matches your desired length. I presume this is what you want to do. its very easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("2of12inf.txt")));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // process the line.
        int lineLength = line.length();
        // assuming each line contains one word, do whatever you want to with this length
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception caught! Should handle it accordingly: " + e);
} finally { 
    be.close();
}
```

Comment: You should use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement here :).

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks for catching that. Try/catch should always be used for I/O

Comment: Not a normal `try/catch` block, I mean the `try-with-resources` statement :D. Read the link for more information.